# Strange Vaadin Combo box behaviour

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin, vaadin7

I have the following UI in my Vaadin app. 1. A USER combo box linked to a users container and 2. a UI table with a list of STUDENTS linked to a students container.

I am periodically refreshing the students container every 10 seconds. However on refresh of the students container, if i have the combo box list selected the items are grayed out and then i have to re-select the combo.

The como list is ok until the refresh, thereafter all the elements are gray.

I dont think this is normal behavior? Any ideas on to how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can put all your elements from SQLContainer to an indexed container and set that as a source to comboBox, alternatively , you can add the values of desired property of SQLContainer to an arrayList and get items from arrayList to add to combo list